# Cannot connect with PostgreSQL datebase using PG'OCaml

Tags: postgresql, ocaml

I've recently tried to use OCaml to deal with Postgres databases. I found PG'Ocaml library and stucked on the very first example. That's the error:

```
$ make
ocamlfind ocamlc -package pgocaml,pgocaml.syntax -syntax camlp4o -c test.ml
File "test.ml", line 7, characters 23-146 (end at line 12, character 2):
Camlp4: Uncaught exception: Unix.Unix_error (20 | CstTag21, "connect", "")

File "test.ml", line 1:
Error: Preprocessor error
make: *** [test.cmo] Error 2
```

Here is somehow similar question (https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/modcaml/2008-05/msg00000.html), but the conclusions doesn't work for me, because logging using

```
$ psql -h localhost -d adam - U adam
```

works completely and I've included line

```
let dbh = PGOCaml.connect ~host:"localhost" ~user:"adam" ~datebase:"adam"
  ~password:"******" () in
```

into my code.

Here is my Makefile:

```
PROJECT := test
LINK_PKG := pgocaml
COMP_PKG := pgocaml,pgocaml.syntax

all: $(PROJECT)

$(PROJECT): $(PROJECT).cmo
    ocamlfind ocamlc -package $(LINK_PKG) -linkpkg -o $@ $<

$(PROJECT).cmo: $(PROJECT).ml
    ocamlfind ocamlc -package $(COMP_PKG) -syntax camlp4o -c $<
```

and that's the whole code:

```
open Printf

let () =
  let dbh = PGOCaml.connect ~host:"localhost" ~user:"adam" ~datebase:"adam"
  ~password:"******" () in

  PGSQL(dbh) "execute" "create temporary table employees (
id serial not null primary key,
name text not null,
salary int4 not null,
email text
)";

  let insert =
    PGPREPARE(dbh) "opt-args"
    "insert into employees (name, salary, email)
values ($name, $salary, $?email)"
  in
  insert "Ann" 10_000_l ();
  insert "Bob" 45_000_l ();
  insert "Jim" 20_000_l ();
  insert ~name:"Mary" ~salary:30_000_l ~email:"mary@example.com" ();

  let rows = PGSQL(dbh) "select id, name, salary, email from employees" in
  List.iter (
    fun (id, name, salary, email) ->
      let email = match email with Some email -> email | None -> "-" in
      printf "%ld %S %ld %S\n" id name salary email
  ) rows;

  let ids = [ 1_l; 3_l ] in
  let rows = PGSQL(dbh) "select id, name, salary, email from employees
where id in $@ids" in
  List.iter (
    fun (id, name, salary, email) ->
      let email = match email with Some email -> email | None -> "-" in
      printf "%ld %S %ld %S\n" id name salary email
  ) rows;

  PGOCaml.close dbh
```

Comment: The error is from camlp4 and on line 7, the first line using PG'OCaml's syntax extension. Thus, it's likely an issue with parsing and nothing to do with connecting to the database. Try simplifying your example.

Comment: You are right, syntax PGSQL(dbh) "..." was the actual problem. Thanks a lot!